# Material UI theme global Dense setting

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to set global Dense setting preferably somewhere inside theme config?
I'm building applications exclusively for desktop users and would like more information to be on the screen.

Gmail already has this option

[image]

And many individual components have property to make them more compact.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default values for any Material-UI component props. See the documentation here: https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#default-props.

For instance to default all Material-UI `List` components to be dense, you would have the following in your theme:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    MuiList: {
      dense: true
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit Global dense]

For aspects that can't be controlled using props, you can use the [overrides](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#css) key of the theme to override CSS for each component.

Comment: Overriding default props definitely helps, but I will need to change it for all components. And not all of them have dense property which means I need to change font size, margins, height etc.. What I'm really looking for is desktop oriented theme or config option(like dark/light)

Comment: There isn't any single config option to do this. It can all be customized in the theme, but you need to customize each component type separately.