# How to create a customised Button using Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Material-UI lets you use `withStyles()` to create a Button with a set of styles, but I wonder if it is at all possible to do the same but with **props** instead, so all the custom buttons I'm creating have the `disableRipple` set to `false`, instead of having to add the prop to each individual button.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56400861/material-ui-theme-global-dense-setting/56447919#56447919

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to override material-ui components default props?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57359439/is-it-possible-to-override-material-ui-components-default-props)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can do this with configuring `globals`.

[Example form docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#default-props):

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    // Name of the component ⚛️
    MuiButtonBase: {
      // The default props to change
      disableRipple: true, // No more ripple, on the whole application !
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: also created a working example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/cool-leftpad-kycsc